# Sending emails from sql sever

Tags: sql, smtp

What is the best way to send email from sql server 2008 (script).

Any sample or online links please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the [Database Mail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175887.aspx) feature and the built-in procedure [sp_send_dbmail](http://sp_send_dbmail).